# Exercises for local class field theory

Tags: class-field-theory

I'm planning to give a mini course about local class field theory with some people. We made a lecture note based on Neukirch's "Class field theory - Bonn lecture". It seems that it will be great if we put some exercises for group cohomology and local class field theory. For group cohomology, Dummit and Foote's "Algebra" gives a lot of problems, so we may use these problems. But the book doesn't contain much problems related to local class field theory, or about Galois cohomology, and the problems are suitable to exercise some homological algebra methods (not number theoretical applications.) Also, Milne's "Class field theory" note contains some problems, too, but there are all about global class field theory. (In this mini course, we will only cover about local class field theory.) Could you offer any other good references for exercises about local class field theory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serre's *Corps Locaux/Local Fields*?

Comment: I still think the book would be twice as useful if someone would have been allowed to add some exercises.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry for late reply. Does it contain good exercises?

Comment: @See-WooLee Serre's book definitely has some exercises.